# HTML / CSS : Removing white-spaces between elements - Benefit of font-size 0.1px (instead of 0)?

Tags: html, css

In CSS it is common to remove white-spaces between elements by setting the font-size of the container element to 0px.

On the child elements becomes set to the normal size again.

I've always applied "font-size: 0" to the container element and that worked fine.

Now I've seen in other people's code that many use "font-size: 0.1px;" instead. For example here: https://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

In section "Break Elements" ...

**What's the benefit of keeping these remaining font-size?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of some sort of solutions for your promlem: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

In my opinion, using `font-size`: 0 / 0.1px might not be the best approch:

> Matt Stow reports that the font-size: 0; technique has some problems
>   on Android. Quote: Pre-Jellybean does not remove the space at all, and
>   Jellybean has a bug whereby the last element randomly has a tiny bit
>   of space. See research.
>
> Also note, if you're sizing fonts in ems, this zero font size thing
>   can be an issue, since ems cascade the children would also have zero
>   font size. Rems would be of help here, otherwise any other
>   non-cascading font-size to bump it back up.
>
> Another weirdness! Doug Stewart showed me that if you use @font-face
>   with this technique, the fonts will lose anti-aliasing in Safari
>   5.0.x. (test case) (screenshot).